# Examples of Linguistic Features?

Tags: theoretical-linguistics

I'm taking a course "Introduction to Translation" and while i'm reading about the things a translator should do before translating a text is to see what are the salient linguistic features in the text? Can you please provide me with examples on that?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks like a homework question with no attempt to own research prior to asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linguistic features is an **extremely broad** phrase. In context of translating, the things I would take particular note of include:

- [register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_%28sociolinguistics%29):  a variety of a language used for a particular purpose or in a particular social setting, a [sociolect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sociolect), [ethnolect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethnolect), etc.
- [dialect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialect), [slang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slang),
- [jargon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jargon): "the technical terminology or characteristic idiom of a special activity or group"
- [tense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_tense) / [aspect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect) : these may not have 1 - 1 mappings
- [lexical aspect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_aspect)
- [alliteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alliteration)
- [puns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pun) & [double entendres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_entendre)
- [idiomatic expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiom)
- cultural proverbs, e.g. a [kotowaza](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_proverbs) in Japanese
- assumed social knowledge that is evident in certain language use, like detecting or displaying sarcasm, irony, and more nuanced tones in writing
- changes in script, orthography, use of capitals, italicization, small caps, quotes, underlining: for example, how do you represent all capitals in a language with two letter cases, in a language that has only majuscules ?

In my opinion, those are things that would be examples when translating. However, *feature* has a plethora of meanings in linguistics. In semantics, it could refer to a semantic class or category. In phonetics, say, a place of articulation. In morphology, a lexical category or inflectional category.